# SQL Query between three tables, get data only from one table

Tags: sql

I have these 3 tables:

**product** table

> id
>
> siteId

**optionsSet** table

> id
>
> productId
>
> ...

**option** table

> id
>
> optionsSetId
>
> code
>
> ...

*Question:*

How can I make a SQL query to select **all** from **option** table by knowing these two: **option.code** and **product.siteId** ?

I know how to do a query with JOIN on two tables, but I am struggling with joining these three tables.

Comment: please add the query which you have tried as well

Comment: I still keep trying different things, none work, not sure which one to post :)

Comment: you can post the one which you feel is the closest to achieving your result. we can help you identify where your going wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    option
WHERE
    code = @code
    AND optionsSetId IN 
    (SELECT
        os.id
    FROM
        optionsSet os
        JOIN product p ON os.productId = p.Id
    WHERE
        p.siteId = @siteId)
```

where @code is your code parameter and @siteId is your siteid parameter

to use inner joins you would have to join all 3 tables together and that would like

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT o.* 
FROM
    option o
    JOIN optionsSet os ON o.optionsSetId = os.Id
    JOIN product p ON os.productId = p.Id
WHERE
    o.code = @code
    AND p.siteId = @site
```

if you notice that requires a `DISTINCT` to only get the data from `option`. It may be simpler and easier to understand but not very efficient.

another option that someone will probably say is way more awesome is using `EXISTS`

```
SELECT
    o.*
FROM
    OPTION o
WHERE
    o.code = @code
    AND EXISTS(
        SELECT
            1
        FROM
            optionsSet os
            JOIN product p ON os.productId = p.Id
        WHERE
            o.optionSetId = os.Id
            AND p.siteId = @siteId
    )
```

I used `EXISTS` exclusively for a few years and the started working on databases with tables that had +100million records and `IN` was faster than `EXISTS` in some cases and identical in the others.  Plus `IN` is less code.

Comment: why not suggest `inner join` on all three tables? its simpler and easier to understand

Comment: what does dbo.[OPTION] do?

Comment: dbo.[option] doesnt do anything.. it just looked like a reserved word in sql 2012 so i wrapped it in brackets

Comment: Your solution works, the only thing I had to change: 'id' to 'os.id' because there was an error: "Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous". I was playing with JOINs only (and not double SELECT) nad couldn't work it out.  Your last comment makes perfect sense. Thank you very much for jour your help :)

Comment: there are a few reasons why i wouldn't want to join all 3 tables when i only want the data from 1 table.. the biggest one is to prevent from having duplicate records and having to do a group by or distinct to get only the data that i need.

Comment: and I suppose without joining 3 tables it is less cpu intensive?

Comment: it certainly is if you have to apply a group by or distinct to eliminate duplicates

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM option
LEFT JOIN product
ON option.code = product.siteId (+)
```

--(+) is a left outter join. This should include all of the values in option.code and all of the values in product that have the same siteId as values in option.

I'm unsure on how you want OptionSet to relate to the other 2 databases though?

if you want to include the third tables result you can just add another join on that table for the condition you want.

Comment: What do you mean by (+) --(+)  ?

Comment: -- is a comment in sql so I was commenting that "(+) is a left outter join". Sorry about the confusion.